# textbox equation with variable answer to another textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to use the value from textbox5 when entered to multiply with a value in cell(v38) and have it show the answer in textbox7

```
Private Sub TextBox7_Change()
Dim value As Integer
 If TextBox5.value > 0 Then
  TextBox7.value = TextBox5.value * Sheet1(v38).value
 Else
  Me.TextBox7.value = 0
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: be more specific, what you are trying to achieve and what you did till now. Are you getting any errors , if yes show them. Imagine you are answering someone question, what info you need

Comment: Textbox7_change Event would trigger a infinite loop..Go with Textbox5_change Event

Answer (score 0):

so this is what i managed to do in the end and it works well.

```html
Private Sub TextBox5_Change()
On Error Resume Next
Dim value As Integer
On Error Resume Next

 If TextBox5.value > 0 Then
 TextBox7.value = Round(TextBox5.value * Range("v38"), 1)
 Else
  Me.TextBox7.value = 0
DoEvents
 End If

End Sub
```